# Service Fabric - Fail to open connection to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I try to open connection to SQL Server 2016 by Service Fabric in my local. I get an exception

```
SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
```

I tried to follow [this](http://blog.citrix24.com/configure-sql-express-to-accept-remote-connections/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38443001/connect-to-local-sql-server-instance-when-running-service-fabric-cluster-in-deve/43255085#43255085). But I still have that problem. Anyone had similar issue ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why am I getting "Cannot Connect to Server - A network-related or instance-specific error"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18060667/why-am-i-getting-cannot-connect-to-server-a-network-related-or-instance-speci)

Comment: I have already followed this answer. no hope. I use  Windows Authentication. Maybe I should have one SQL Authentication in this case.

Comment: Exactly! by creating a SQL authentication and use that one instead of Windows Authentication. my problem has been solved. I followed this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/sql/virtual-machines-windows-sql-connect]